# How to align select button onto same line as the terms and conditions text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Regarding this site
http://gdnfitness.com/contact-us

The outcome required is to have the select box display on the same line as the 'I agree to the Terms & Conditions' text, ideally at the end, but can be the beginning if easier.

I have tried targeting the select box position and cycling through its position, but this does not seem to make an impact.

This is a Wordpress site using Elementor

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want make center checkbox just change input and label position in code . 
in Elementor you can change code and make custom .

but if you want checkbox left the text like all term & condition in all site . 
you must move label and input in `span` tag **elementor-field-option**

i check all in inspect and it's work . edit Elementor code custom

Answer (score 1):

You need to style the parent element `<div class="elementor-field-subgroup">`

Give it the following `css`:

```
{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-basis: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```